# Extract time using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have scraped some data from the yellow pages using scrapy.

The hours of the business provided from scraping are in a 12-hour format and I need to convert it into 24 hours.

The format for the business hours I scraped are:

```
Mon - Fri:,10:00 am - 7:00 pm.
```

I need to extract the two values for opening and closing time, convert them both into 24-hour format and then concatenate the string back together again.

As a result, I need to devise a regex that will extract the time and then change it into a 24 hour format. 
The final string should (as per previous example) should be:

```
Mon - Fri:,10:00 - 19:00
```

I have tried different regex. I tried the following:

```
import re

txt = 'Mon - Fri:,10:00 am - 7:00 pm'
data = re.findall(r'\s(\d{2}\:\d{2}\s?(?:AM|PM|am|pm))', txt)
print(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am not python developer but we can in this way in javascript. you can convert logic into python

in this way you can convert this time to miltary time (24 hour)

https://jsfiddle.net/1hxojLdf/2/

```
let text='Mon - Fri:,10:00 am - 7:00 pm';
const regex=/(\w+\s-\s\w+:.)(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s(am|pm))\s-\s(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\s(am|pm))/;
const result=text.match(regex);
let timeone=result[2];
let timetwo=result[4];
timeone= moment(timeone,"h:mm A").format('HH:mm');
timetwo= moment(timetwo,"h:mm A").format('HH:mm');

text=result[1]+timeone+"-"+timetwo;
alert(text)
```